# Set SESSION values from array

Tags: php, session

I'm having trouble with this so I wan't to get this going, I have a PHP class that will handle sessions, so when I call IniciarSesion function I will send and object with param and value to set into SESSION, but I'm having trouble assigning it into the session. Here is my class code.

```
class Sesiones{
    public function IniciarSesion($params, $url){
        session_start();
        //Iterar parametros de array params y setearlo en session
        foreach ($params as $param){
            $_SESSION[$param["param"]] = $param["val"];
        }
        //URL para redireccionar
        if (isset($url)){
            header("Location: ".$url);
        }
    }
    public function CerrarSesion($url){
        session_destroy();
        exit();
        //El parametro URL es para saber a que URL redireccionar
        if (isset($url)){
            header("Location: ".$url);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the structure call will have:

```
$user_params = [["param"=>"id", "val"=>1457],["param"=>"user", "val"=>"Force"]];
$user_url = "perfil.php?id=1457";

$init_session = new Sesiones();
$init_session->IniciarSesion($user_params, $user_url);
```

Where I'm doing it wrong?

**EDIT**

My problem is that $_SESSION wasn't populating, and since here on my job I can't access the error logs and PHP erroe messages are disabled I had hard time finding it, but when I changed user it worked, so I rolled back to main user and access value by value and found that $user_params can get this data:

```
$user_params = [["param"=>"apellido", "val"=>&Aacute;mbar]];
```

I think this is a completely different issue, I don't know why there are no "" to set it as string, but since this comes from an external web service I need to format on my Sesiones class

Comment: *What* isn't working? Please describe your issue better.

Comment: Your exact code seems to be populating `$_SESSION` just fine: https://3v4l.org/mvlBE

Comment: The problem was SESSION isn't populating, but I think I found the issue and don't know what to do, editing question now

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding of code check this foreach

```
foreach ($user_params as $key => $val){
     $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
}
```

Comment: gonna try this instead, but I'm editing question now I found something else